# Computer Name contains a space. How to change it?

Tags: android-studio, computer-name

My computer name is hp 15-ab032tx. Because of the space in the name, when i try to store my android studio project, it gives me an error.

I cannot store it on the Desktop either because the address becomes C:\Users\hp 15-ab032tx\Desktop\AndroidProject which contains a space.
Adding "",'' is not working.

How to change the name of the computer? Going to Properties->Computer Name ->Change did not change the name.
Also, if the name cannot be changed then where can I store my projects?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you *username* (`hp 16-ab032tx`) is the problem, and that can't be easily changed. Store your project in a path without spaces (like `C:\Projects\`).